# Does adding a perpendicular component to a vector change its angle?

Tags: vectors

[image]

So, suppose we have a vector in the x-y plane making angle $\alpha$ with $y$,now suppose we add an orange vector in direction of z axis:

[image]
This leads us to a blue vector, now is the pictorial representation true ? i.e: the alpha angle is same even when we add a component perpendicular to the vector or is it just a illusion in the picture?

Comment: Your orange vector is not clear to me, sorry.

Comment: There's nothing really to be sorry about. I'll redraw it @VIVID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well let's call the original two vectors $a$ and $b$, whose angle is $\alpha$. This means (by the definition of angle), that $$
  \cos \alpha = \frac{ \langle a,b \rangle}{|a||b|}
$$

Let's check the angle if you add a perpendicular vector $p$ to one of the vectors: now $$
  \cos \alpha' = \frac{ \langle a + p,b \rangle}{|a + p||b|} = \frac{ \langle a ,b \rangle + \langle p, b \rangle}{|a + p||b|} = \frac{ \langle a,b \rangle}{|a + p||b|}
$$

So you can see that the denominator is strictly greater (assuming that $p$ is not a zero vector), and the numerator doesn't change, so the fraction is strictly smaller. Because $\cos$ is decreasing on the range we're interested in, the new angle has to be strictly larger

Unless, of course, if $a$ and $b$ were orthogonal to begin with, in which case both fractions would be zero, and so the angle didn't change.

Comment: Right, thank you.

Comment: I see I was beaten on time

Answer (score 1):

In general there's no need for the angle to be still $\alpha$. From a linear algebra perspective, say $v$ is the black vector, which forms an angle $\alpha$ with the vector $e_{1}=(1,0)$, where $e_{1},e_{2}$ is the canonical base of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. Then by definition $\cos\alpha=\frac{<v,e_{1}>}{\|v\|\|e_{1}\|}$. Let $w$ the blue vector which is obtained by adding a vector $v'$ to $v:$ $w=v+v'$. Let $\beta$ the angle between $w$ and $v$, then:
$$\cos\beta=\frac{<w,v>}{\|w\|\|v\|}$$
Now, $<w,v>=<v+v',v>=<v,v>+<v',v>$ by bilinearity, thus:
$$\cos\beta=\frac{<w,v>}{\|w\|\|v\|}=\frac{<v,v>}{\|w\|\|v\|}+\frac{<v',v>}{\|w\|\|v\|}=\frac{\|v\|}{\|w\|\|v\|}+\cos\alpha\geq\cos\alpha$$
Meaning that $\beta$ and $\alpha$ can't be the same.